# load_and_authorize_resource with collection and custom model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, cancan

I have controller with many custom actions:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def fizz

  end


  def buzz

  end

  ...
end
```

And I want to load and authorize Bar collection (without repeating `@bars = Bar.all`) into these two methods.

Something like that:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :bar, :collection, :only => [:fizz, :buzz, ...]
```

But this simply doesn't work, `@bars` variable is `nil` in the all actions. Please, help me to understand what is going wrong and how can I make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me ([source](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/367)):

```
load_and_authorize_resource :bar, :parent => false
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a before_filter in your controller:

```
before_filter :load_and_authorize_resource, :only => [:fizz, :buzz]

private

def load_and_authorize_resource
   @bars = Bar.all
end
```

Comment: Thanks for a good idea, but it's preferably for me to use default CanCan methods and don't create new ones.

Comment: oh, okay, i am not familiar with CanCan. Good luck! :)